# what is the use of Miscellaneous Folder in SSIS Solution

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

What exactly is the use of **Miscellaneous** folder in the SSIS Solution folder hierarchy?
I have use many packages and solutions as a part of the project,but never used this folder.I do understand that ,one can import various files over here.
Can any body tell the practical scenario ,where this folder is being used?

Comment: Personally, I've used it for the storage of associated documentation and processes related to the SSIS package.

Comment: All other files that you need in your project and that do not have the extension .dtsx will be dropped in this folder (f.e. documentation or SQL files).
And if you install BIDSHELPER (bidshelper.codeplex.com) it will store the BIML files (for generating packages) in that same folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My two primary use cases are [Biml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biml) files (which allow me to generate SSIS) and any sql scripts for migration of Environment and configuration of values.

Comment: would like to execute sql script stored in misc folder from ssis. how do I ?

Answer (score 1):

We can keep the files which is not associated to the project or solution, but we will be tracking and using it in the solution. So for the quick accessing the file we can use this folder